# Как присоединить 3 таблицу с помощью JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть SQL JOIN запрос на 2 таблицы

```
SELECT
  users.*,
  sum(payments.amount) as `summ`
FROM `users`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `payments` ON `users`.`id` = `payments`.`user_id`
WHERE payments.created_at  BETWEEN '$yesterday' and '$today' AND `status` = '2'
GROUP BY user_id
```

Как добавить 3 таблицу в этот JOIN запрос?
Нужно добавить таблицу qiwi_withdraws тоже объединить её по ID, а затем так же сделать выборку по status=2, created_at, подсчитать и сгруппировать по amount

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Привет! Напиши, пожалуйста, все 3 таблицы, чтобы точно понимать. А так же весь SQL запрос поправь и отформатируй в читаемый вид, сейчас такоое

Comment: *Как добавить 3 таблицу в этот JOIN запрос?* Точно так же, как "добавлена" вторая. Сразу после второй таблицы, непосредственно перед WHERE. Вот только зачем используется ***LEFT** JOIN*, когда на самом деле выполняется *INNER JOIN*?

Comment: @Alexxosipov Извините за долгое отсутствие. Прикрепил скринами выше.

Comment: @Akina Пробовал сразу после 2 добавить. Но, в итоге максимум добился того, что результат выходил 0. Не осиливаю пока 3 таблицы. С трудом 2 таблицы осилил. Нормального примера под мою задачу не нашёл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таблицу вторую присоединить можно так же, как и первую:

```
FROM users u
JOIN payments p ON u.id = p.user_id
JOIN qiwi_withdraws q ON u.id = q.user_id
```

Для Вашей задачи это не подойдет. Во всяком случае, я не знаю, как взять нужные суммы без подзапросов. Если их использовать, то Ваш запрос может выглядеть так:

```
SELECT users.*, 
(SELECT sum(amount) FROM payments 
    WHERE user_id = users.id AND status = 2 
    AND (created_at BETWEEN '$yesterday' AND '$today')) as payments_sum,
(SELECT sum(amount) FROM qiwi_withdraws 
    WHERE user_id = users.id AND status = 2
    AND (created_at BETWEEN '$yesterday' AND '$today')) as qiwi_sum
FROM users
```

Comment: Я скажу кратко - Я ВАС ПРОСТО ОБОЖАЮ!!! ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО. Всё работает!)))

Comment: @РусланЛысенко не за что, рад, что удалось помочь ))

Comment: я рано обрадовался(( Сначала все таблицы соединяются, это хорошо. Но, затем происходит выгрузка абсолютно всех записей, хотя стоит параметр BETWEEN. Ну и последняя ошибка, это параметр GROU BY он не хочет группировать. Если можете, дайте свои контакты, если можно. Я бы вам туда отписал, готов даже заплатить. А то я намучался знатно.

Comment: Странно, тут группировка и не нужна совсем... Напишите на stepanovm77@yandex.ru попробую помочь чем смогу